# Python 2.7: How to extend a class from an imported base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-2.7

New to python, apologies if this is nub stuff:

Writing a small module (maybe a package, eventually?). It's gotten too big for single file, so I'm moving my larger classes to individual files. All of my classes extend a base class I use to house some rudimentary functions.

Here's a generic form of my problem:

**runtime.py:**

```
import baseclass
import subclass

#do stuff
```

---

**baseclass.py**

```
class BaseClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def sharedMethod(self):
        pass
        # shared functionality
```

---

**subclass.py**

```
class SubClass(baseclass.BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
```

The traceback reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/runtime.py", line 2, in <module>
    import baseclass, subclass
  File "path/to/subclass.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Subclass(baseclass.BassClass):
  NameError: name 'baseclass' is not defined
```

If I import `baseclass` into `subclass.py` it works fine, but this seems to imply that every class which extends `baseclass` needs to import it, and it *musn't* be the case that the appropriate way to do this is import `baseclass` over and over again.

I'd like to be able to import classes from separate files in the order that they build upon each other, I just don't know how to do it. Advice?

---

**Note:** All the answers were helpful/correct. I just chose, for the "correct" one, the answer that was most thorough/most likely to be useful to everyone. Cheers, thanks. :)

Comment: But this is how it works. How should a SubClass know its BaseClass if it wasn't imported previously?

Comment: After you get past this error, I think you will need to change the "super" call to `baseclass.BaseClass.__init__(self)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you said is exactly right.  You have to import baseclass in any file where you want to use it.  The right way is indeed to import it "over and over" if you have many files that use it.

But that doesn't mean that every *class* that extends baseclass needs to import it.  It just means that every *module* that uses baseclass needs to import it.  There is no need to have just one class in a given file, and there's no particular reason to do things that way.  It's perfectly fine to have `import baseclass` in one file and then, in that file, define several new classes all inherited from baseclass.  That is a good way to do things.  Don't split up each class into its own file unless each class really is big enough and complex enough to warrant that.

In addition, doing `import baseclass` in many files doesn't cost anything in terms of resources.  The actual `baseclass.py` file is only run once, and the same module is re-used on later imports, so you don't pay any extra penality in terms of performance for importing it many times.

`import` is the way that Python files access stuff from other Python modules.  You just can't use things from one file in another file without importing them.

Incidentally, why are you putting that `__name__ = "SubClass"` business into your modules?

Comment: Thanks a million, this answers my question; I didn't realize that there was no overhead to keep importing.

Some of my modules do indeed have many classes, but a few classes are 1k+ lines and... I don't like scrolling? ;)

I thought the __name__ parameter was just good form, ie. part of properly commented code. Is this not so?

Comment: @Jonline.  Re `__name__`: No.  Where did you get that info?  `__name__` will be internally set by Python to the name of your module (e.g., it will be `"baseclass"` for `baseclass.py` and so on).  Likewise a `__name__` wil be set on each class (the BaseClass class will have `__name__` set to `"BaseClass"`).  You shouldn't set `__name__` explicitly unless you're doing something funky (e.g., wrapping a class with another class and trying to make it "look the same" as the wrapped class).

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I was thus informed by a programmer friend IRL and suspect the error is with my understanding of the advice, haha. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jonline: No problem, enjoy Python!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, modules behave like seperate programs. So, if you import baseclass in runtime.py, it will not be imported into subclass.py. subclass.py must import baseclass itself.